Why can std::tuple contain references?
I learned ages ago that Standard Library containers won't accept references. E.g. this simple program won't compile because of attempting to create a vector of int&:
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int&> v;  
  return 0;
}

Why, then, can you have a tuple of references? E.g. this program seems to successfully create a tuple of references to variables in the current scope:
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    auto tuple_ref = std::tuple<int&, int&>{i, j};

    for (tuple_ref = std::tuple<int, int>{0, 0}; 
         i < 5 && j < 2; 
         ++i, ++j) {
        cout << i << ", " << j << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

What are the rules about what/when/why Standard Library containers can or cannot have references?

For one thing, std::vector<T> needs to know how much memory to allocate for n instances of T. But n*sizeof(T) doesn't work when T is a reference type; sizeof(U&) == sizeof(U). Since a reference is not an object, it's not even meaningful to ask how much storage it occupies.

std::tuple is not a container..

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

struct foo { int& a; int& b; }; - see how that works? A tuple is not very different.

references are not reseatable, you can't put them in containers, but you can use reference_wrapper

You can, of course, create a vector of structs where the the structs contain references. But if you do you have to reserve space in the vector first before adding them.

As stated in the comments, std::tuple is not a container. It does not do any dynamic allocation so it does not need to know size of the referenced type. You can think of it like of a syntactic sugar for a C struct (that obviously can hold references).

you might want to read ISO C++ Standard (ISO/IEC 14882), 20.4.1 Tuples In general, paragraph 1, and 23.3.6.1 Class template vector overview, paragraph 1:

a tuple type as the class template tuple that can be instantiated with any number of arguments. Each template argument specifies the type ofan element in the tuple. Consequently, tuples are heterogeneous, fixed-size collections of values ...


A vector is a sequence container that supports random access iterators. In addition, it supports (amortized) constant time insert and erase operations at the end; insert and erase in the middle take linear time. Storage management is handled automatically, though hints can be given to improve efficiency. The elements of a vector are stored contiguously ...

